# Scraping skips some of the page url and does not write all values in CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python. I just started yesterday. I want to scrape a website and collect data in the dictionary. 
All the imports are added at the beginning of python script

```
title_and_urls = {} #dictionary
totalNumberOfPages = 12
for x in range(1,int(totalNumberOfPages)+1):
    url_pages = 'https://abd.com/api?&page=' +str(x)+'&year=2017'
    resp = requests.get(url_pages, timeout=60)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', {"class": "block2"}):
        a = div.find('a')
        h3 = a.find('h3')
        print(h3,url_pages) #prints correct
        title_and_urls[h3.text] = base_enthu_url+a.attrs['href']

print(title_and_urls)


with open('dict.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in title_and_urls.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

There are a few issues here
1. I have total 12 pages but it skipped pages 7 and 8
2. The print line `print(h3,url_pages)` printed 60 items while csv file only has 36.

I appreciate all the help and explanation. Please suggest best practice

Comment: Can you share the real url? Maybe the query changes for those specific pages for some reason. Also: do you need to use BeautifulSoup? I've had a better experience scraping for several pages with Scrapy.

Comment: @A.Lorefice thanks for the comment. There is no change on those specific pages. I have manually scrapped it and it works. So I learned this in 1 day and I did not come across Scrappy on tutorials I found online. Also, why dictionary is only holding 36 items while it's printing 60 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use try function

```
**title_and_urls = {} #dictionary
totalNumberOfPages = 12
for x in range(1,int(totalNumberOfPages)+1):
    try:
        url_pages = 'https://abd.com/api?&page=' +str(x)+'&year=2017'
        resp = requests.get(url_pages, timeout=60)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
        for div in soup.find_all('div', {"class": "block2"}):
            a = div.find('a')
            h3 = a.find('h3')
            print(h3,url_pages) #prints correct
            title_and_urls[h3.text] = base_enthu_url+a.attrs['href']
    except:
        pass


with open('dict.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in title_and_urls.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])**
```

Comment: Nothing changed, I still have same issues

Comment: updated my code, please check how many lines print and how many lines in csv

Comment: Can you please explain the code you modified? what I was doing wrong?

Comment: you have written print command twice, that was printing last line again. 
 **print(title_and_urls)**

Comment: what about skipping url pages and only getting fewer data in a CSV instead of full data?

Comment: Can you please check this code reply and just play it. You will see the issue I was talking about. https://repl.it/repls/VigorousImpeccableProgramminglanguages

Comment: Can you tell me which url you are not getting in csv but in print screen ??
I am getting all the data that is printing.
I think I am getting your point, the data that is skipping is the website issue, website is not extracting full page some time and some times its giving full data.
I made some changes in your code please have a look.

Comment: There are 12 pages and total 72 results. However, every time I run the program it returns a random number of results. Sometimes its 36 and other time it's 41. The program is not consistent.

Comment: True, but there is no glitch in your code. its the website that is not providing proper output

Comment: I tried running the program multiple times on my work laptop. Funny thing is it works perfectly fine. I've used the same code on my personal laptop and it doesn't work. I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue. Using repl.it same issues as my personal laptop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180382/discussion-between-supritshah1289-and-sushant-kathuria).